# Apache Server Log-502 error

Tags: apache-http-server

I am seeing 502 error: Bad Gateway:The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. My Apache logs is showing this:

[image: log screenshot]

Could anyone please help me in understanding this error?

Comment: The line you provided is just a `notice`. It's not the reason for the error. You have to check for messages tagged as `error` or `emerg`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. my webapp started giving me the 502 error..after a hotfix applied upgraded apache 2.2 to apache 2.4 . I tried changing the httpd-default.conf file to change the time-out interval for the reverse proxy server, but I am still seeing the rror. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Please provide full log message, or at least the events tagged as `error` or `emerg` (please don't paste pictures, it's better to add the plain text in your question).